# In what controller's action better to check users rights?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In '**new**' or '**create**'?
In '**edit**' or '**update**'?

I check with this line:

```
correct_user(@car.user) if not current_user.admin?
```

where

```
def correct_user(user)
   redirect_to root_path if current_user != user
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these actions all need the admin right, you'd better use a before filter.

```
before_filter :correct_user,  :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
```

Comment: the question is: Can user make 'create' actions without 'new'? or can he make 'update' actions without 'edit'?

Comment: Yes, he can forge a post request.

Answer (score 1):

In every single place a user cannot access if he doesn't have the permissions.

I would structure the code so that you don't have to write it in the action:

```
before_filter :load_car, :redirect_unless_correct_user!, :except => :index

protected
def load_car
  @car = Car.find(params[:car_id])
end

def redirect_unless_correct_user!
  redirect_to(root_path) unless (current_user == @car.user) || user.admin?
end
```